# c++11 threads don't modify same values

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm writing a program that (ideally) requires two threads to run simultaneously.

I have a global vector variable myObjects to keep track of my Objects:

```
vector<Object> myObjects;
```

And a object of type `MoND` that will be doing the heavy lifting.
It is initialized with the vector as an argument and it pushes "Objects" into the vector. No problem so far.

```
MoND  mySim =  MoND(myObjects);
```

In main, a method of mySim needs to be called with `myObjects` as an argument.
In a non-threaded version I used for testing, this works (run bails out after 100 iterations):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ...
  mySim.Run(myObjects);// Run simulation on Objects
  glutMainLoop();      // Enter the event-processing loop                                                                                            
  return 0;
}
```

By works I mean changes the properties of the `Object`s stored in `myObjects`.
This needs to run persistently and concurrently so it's not ideal.

Using threading:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ...
  thread t1(&MoND::Run, mySim, myObjects);// Run simulation on Objects
  glutMainLoop();      // Enter the event-processing loop                                                                                            
  return 0;
}
```

This doesn't have the desired effect.
`Run()` receives myObjects and changes their values, but these are not translated to the `myObjects` being used by the main thread. Is another instance of `myObjects` created in memory for the new thread? 
(yes, I did pass by reference and the non-threaded version does update the values just fine)

So I know the logic works (everything works as expected without threading).
I have tried to use atomic but to be honest I can't get it to work with a vector or its contents.

How can I force the two threads to work on the same instance of `myObjects` in memory (i.e. get them to share the variable)?

Some points:

- No, I'm not worried about thread safety as only one thread writes, the other just reads (order of reading/writing is unimportant)
- `Run()` updates the values of private variables in objects of class Object through methods `SetPos(args..)` and `SetVel(args..)`

Comment: `std::thread` copies the arguments. Use `std::ref`. Do note that reading while writing can still cause problems.

Comment: "No, I'm not worried about thread safety as only one thread writes, the other just reads (order of reading/writing is unimportant)" You probably should be: concurrent access to the same object by two threads - at least one of which is modifying the object - is a data race. Programs with data races have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `std::thread` constructor copies its arguments to make sure that they are still alive when they are being operated on.

To avoid that, you can use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
thread t1(&MoND::Run, mySim, std::ref(myObjects));
```

Here you promise that you take care of your object's lifetime.

`std::bind` and `std::async` exhibit the same behavior out of the same reasons.

Note that `mySim` is also being copied, here however you could also pass a pointer if don't want the copy.

Comment: Thank you very much, will look into std::bind and std::ref for future use

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable you want to share across threads is a global, the solution is even simpler: Don't pass it as an argument at all.

Global variables are visible throughout the program.