# Thread calls destructor many times

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, destructor

i'm new to `std::thread` in c++11. i tried passing a `functor-object` to a thread instead of a `lambda`.

however, the output i got suprised me: it seems like the destructor is called 6x times.

Code Snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct A
{
  A()
  { 
    std::cout << "creating A" << std::endl; 
  }

  void operator()()
  {
    std::cout << "calling ()-operator" << std::endl;
  }

  ~A()
  { 
    std::cout << "destroying A" << std::endl;   
  }
};

int main()
{
  {
    std::thread t( (A()) );
    t.join();
  }
  std::cin.get();
}
```

the output i get (msvc11) is

```
creating A
calling ()-operator
destroying A
destroying A
destroying A
destroying A
destroying A
destroying A
```

Any explanation is greatly appreciated.!

Comment: I'd add a copy constructor to see how many times it has been called...

Comment: You could also add output to a copy and move constructor, to see what the implementation is doing with the object. It's an implementation detail of your particular standard library implementation, however.

Comment: kudos, the copy-constructor got called 5 times, therefore those 6 dtor-calls make perfectly sense. the question still remaining is: why are there 5 copys?

Comment: ok, things are getting unclear now: i added a move-constructor
   A(const A&& m){...} 
which is getting called 5 times now, no calls to copy-constructor anymore. however, dtor still got called 6 times.

from my understanding, a object that was moved e.g. in another thread leaves kind of an invalid state and the dtor must not be called on that

Comment: This might be of interest to you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191884/893693

Comment: Use `std::ref` to pass A into the thread.

Comment: @user3796535 An object which is moved from still needs to be destroyed. A move must leave the source object in an "unspecified, but valid" state. The dtor is of course called on such objects as well.

Comment: thank you. i thought that it doesn't use any copy here since the arg passed is an r-value (however, don't quote me on that). in my other attemp i used std::move but i can't quite distinguish which calls come from moving in the thread and which happen internally. my guess would be at most one call to move-constructor when moving A to the thread. however, i am cionfused about the other 4 calls.

Comment: i tried using std::ref and it worked at least somehow as expected ( one call to ctor, operator() and dtor ), so thank you very much for this. but is there a simple explanation for the behaviour above?

Comment: @user3796535: Sure, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread . You are missing out some implicit calls to auto generated `operator=` and `copy ctors`. As others have suggested, plotting those + the move versions may give you a hint. It is very easy to create temporary objects.

Comment: Simple? Not really because it depends on RT library implementation (imagine you _may_ have a copy for each internal function call and assignment). Try to write your own class for threads...you may need 3 to 20 copies of such object...

Comment: i have no idea how a thread is exactly working behin the scenes or why you might need at least 3 copies. but i'm new to multithreading so maybe one day all of that makes perfectly sense. from my (too) simple point of view, the copy-ctor would be called once to create a copy of my object in the other threads memory. would the answer be too verbose?

Comment: It is not the threading itself. It is the implementation of std::thread. This may happen in any other function or class as this behaviour is indeed implementation defined.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i almost forgot that with oter stl-classes (vectors, maps, etc) and algorithms (...) moving and copying already happens extensively behind the scenes. thank you for all your kind answers, again, i really appreciate them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't catch all paths the object can be created. Add a copy constructor to `A`:

```
A( A const &a )
{
    std::cout << "creating A (copy)" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. as i said in the comments above, i added copy and move destructors and the object does indeed got copied/moved around. using std::ref does not show such behaviour. however, are there any explanation why the object gets copied around that much or is it just msvc11's implemantation?

Comment: @user3796535, it's only msvc11 implementation. As far as I remember gcc produces program that creates/destroys `A` object only twice.